# NetLogoのコマンドについて: ぶつかったことを判定したい

Tags: untagged

NetLogo初心者です。”ある種のタートルが別のタートルにぶつかったら”動きを変えるというプログラムを組みたいのですが、””内の状況をどのようなコマンドを使えば良いでしょうか？宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 同一時点での「ある種のタートル」の位置(`show [list xcor ycor] of turtle 0`)と「別のタートル」の位置(`show [list xcor ycor] of turtle 1`)を比較してみるのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: レスポンスありがとうございます。特定のタートルというよりは、”Aという種のタートルがB という種のタートルにぶつかったら全て”ということをしたいのですが、それって可能でしょうか？